# Why can't I add more than 1000 characters in my textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, razor

I have a textarea called editReportingPeriodCalc in a Razor html partial called _FormEditSiteGBReportingPeriodCalculationScreen, recreated below:

```
@*_FormEditSiteGBReportingPeriodCalculationScreen*@
<style>
    div.col-md-12 {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    textarea#editReportingPeriodCalc {
        height: 220px;
    }
</style>
<form>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <textarea 
                  id="editReportingPeriodCalc" 
                  class="form-control" 
                  rows="5">
        </textarea>
        <button type="button"
                class="btn btn-primary"
                data-bind="click: SaveEditedSiteGBReportingPeriodCalculation">
            Save
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <button class="btn btn-primary m-r-5"
                style="float:right"
                data-bind="click: CloseEditSiteGBReportingPeriodCalculationModal">
            <span class="fa fa-icon fa-backward" aria-hidden="true"></span> Back
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix">
    </div>
</form>
```

_FormEditSiteGBReportingPeriodCalculationScreen is nested in an Index.cshtml file, recreated below:

```
@*Index.cshtml*@
@model CIS.Domain.ViewModels.Admin.DistrictViewModel
@using System.Web.Script.Serialization
@using CIS.Common;
@using CIS.Domain.ViewModels.Shared;
@using CIS.Web.Utilities.Helpers;

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Admin - Site";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutView.cshtml";
}

@section styles {
    <link href="~/Content/plugins/dataTables/dataTables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/plugins/dataTables/dataTables.responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/plugins/dataTables/buttons.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/plugins/select2/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/plugins/cropper/cropper.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <style type="text/css">
        .image-profile {
            height: 220px;
            line-height: 175px;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 72px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            overflow: hidden;
            -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
            -moz-border-radius: 4px;
            border-radius: 4px;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .image-upload {
            height: 220px;
            line-height: 175px;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 72px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            overflow: hidden;
            -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
            -moz-border-radius: 4px;
            border-radius: 4px;
            width: 100%;
            border: 2px solid #E2E7EB;
        }

        .modal {
            overflow: scroll;
        }
    </style>
}


@section scripts {
    <script>
        var initData = @Html.Raw(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model));


        var pointsPossibleValue = @Html.Raw(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(SessionHelper<UserModel>.Instance.DataValue.Modules.Where(x => x.Name == AppConstants.SystemModule.PointsPossibleEditable).FirstOrDefault().View));

        var sitesAssignmentValue = @Html.Raw(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(SessionHelper<UserModel>.Instance.DataValue.Modules.Where(x => x.Name == AppConstants.SystemModule.SitesAssignment).FirstOrDefault().View));

    </script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/Plugins/cropper/canvas-to-blob.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/Plugins/cropper/cropper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/Plugins/masked-input/masked-input.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/Plugins/select2/select2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/Plugins/select2/select2.knockout.js"></script>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/dataTables")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/site")
}

@* -- System Modules --*@
@{
    var userModel = SessionHelper<UserModel>.Instance.DataValue;
    var systemModule = userModel.Modules.Where(x => x.Name == AppConstants.SystemModule.SiteSettings).FirstOrDefault();
    var _PageAccess = systemModule;


    <script>
        var _PageAccess = @Html.Raw(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(systemModule));
        var _DefaultSiteProfile = @Html.Raw(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(AppConfigurations.DefaultSiteProfile));

    </script>
}

@section modals {
    <div class="modal fade" id="editSiteGBReportingPeriodCalculationModal" data-model="SiteGBCalculationFormModel" style="z-index:1252;">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header bg-silver">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Calculation </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    @Html.Partial("_FormEditSiteGBReportingPeriodCalculationScreen")
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

All javascript from site.js pertaining to adding and removing text to and from the editReportingPeriodCalc textarea (bundled and added via the following line in Index.cshtml: @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/site")) is recreated below:

```
EditSiteGBReportingPeriodCalculationPopUp: function () {
                var reportingPeriodCalcValue = $('#reportingPeriodCalc').val();

                $('#editReportingPeriodCalc').val(reportingPeriodCalcValue);
                $('#editSiteGBReportingPeriodCalculationModal').modal({
                    backdrop: 'static',
                    keyboard: true,
                    show: true
                })
            },
```

The data prepopulating the editReportingPeriodCalc textarea from the database is a string.  The string will correctly display regardless of length.  However, if a user clicks in the textarea and begins typing, any extra characters causing the total number of characters in the textarea to exceed 1000 characters are immediately deleted.  If any additional characters are added, they appear for a second and then are immediately deleted, like someone is rapidly hitting the Backspace key.

I tried increasing the height of the textarea, changing any overflow attributes from 'auto' to 'visible', deleting overflow attributes altogether, and looking for event listeners that might be limiting the number of characters allowed in the textarea.  I was expecting these attempts to resolve the issue.

Comment: The symptoms seem very similar to submitting the form and getting the page refreshed. Does adding a submit handler to the form which logs the submit event **and** cancels it make any difference?